# Why do I get null pointer exception in this code?

Tags: java, autoboxing

```
public class Test {

    Integer i;
    int j;

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
       Test t = new Test ();
       t.go();
    }

    public void go() {
       j=i;
       System.out.println(j);
       System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

**Output :** Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.go(Test.java:12)
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)

Comment: Works for me...can you paste the error _verbatim_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's obviously not the error.  You will get a runtime NullPointerException because you're unboxing a null reference (`i`) into a primitive (`j`).  See JLS [§5.1.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8).

The reason `i` is null is that instance fields are initialized to 0, null, or false by default.

Comment: Rightly spotted. +1. But the error `go cannot be resolved or is not a field` is not at all about this, I wonder. It should be NPE.